# WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/safe-json/dist/esm/index.js

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethers.js

[image]

I was using Wagmi Wallet Connect and encountered a problem. The application did not respond when I tried to execute a project, and I would like to resolve the warning issue that appears.

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?

The issue I experienced was not related to wagmi or ethers.js. I have already attempted to resolve the problem by trying different solutions, including changing the version of react-scripts.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer:

Please make `.env` file in your project root folder.

The content of `.env` file is same as below.

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Please try and let me know the result.